# PHP mail() function not sending email

Tags: php, email

I am attempting to send an email using the `mail()` `PHP` function. I had it working until I attempted to give it a subject of "User registration", then the mail is not sent!

Heres the code (have simplified it greatly)

```
$to = $this->post_data['register-email'];
$message = 'Hello etc';
$headers = 'From: noreply@example.com' . "\r\n" ;
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; chareset=iso-8859-1\r\n';
$headers .= 'From: Website <admin@example.com>';
mail($to, 'User Registration', $message, $headers);
```

I also attempted to use a variable containing the string of text but that didnt work.

Why is it not sending the mail when I add the subject exception?

Thanks

EDIT: updated code thats still not working

```
$to = $this->post_data['register-email'];
$message = 'Hello etc';

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Website <admin@example.com>';
mail($to, 'User Registration', $message, $headers);
```

Comment: Is this code running on Linux or Windows? If Windows what PHP version you running on?

Comment: Also you don't show us how you're adding the "Subject:", can you add that.

Comment: You've got a typo error, charset, not "chareset"

Comment: @crm Try using this `$to = $_POST['register-email'];` instead of `$to = $this->post_data['register-email'];`

Comment: Thanks, but its still not playing ball

Comment: @crm Try removing the space at the of `$headers = 'From: noreply@example.com' . "\r\n" ;` to read as `$headers = 'From: noreply@example.com' . "\r\n";` I've seen cases like this where having a space caused havoc.

Comment: @crm Wait a minute. You have two `From:` this `$headers = 'From: noreply@example.com' . "\r\n" ;` and `$headers .= 'From: Website <admin@example.com>';` remove one and try again.

Comment: @crm updated my answer try it out

Comment: @Breezer after seeing my above comment?

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes removed one from, added mime and changed the order of the headers, should work now =/

Comment: @Breezer Since the problem is obvious.

Comment: @Breezer I updated my question with the still not working code you guys suggested.

Comment: @Fred-ii- well not by the information that was given, then I assumed that somehow one of them are ignored since he "only" added subject to his script

Comment: @Breezer Well the OP will need post the form to go with it. I suspect something in there. Your answer should work, however I'm not too keen on the `$this->post_data` since this belongs to a class or a PHPmailer function, I do believe. I doubt we're seeing full code here.

Comment: @crm You need to post your full code and form. I don't particularly get `$this->post_data` - I suspect that is a PHPmailer function.

Comment: @Fred-ii- `$this->post_data['register-email']` simply holds the recipients email address. So after simple validation the user is sent an automatic email. All was working okay until I starting playing with the subject :/

Comment: @crm Try putting the subject inside double-quotes then `"User Registration"` or assign it as a variable `$subject="User Registration";` then use `mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);`

Comment: @crm So, any luck with my above said comment?

Answer (score 9):

On your 4th line you're using `'` that handles everything inside of it as a string so change

```
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; chareset=iso-8859-1\r\n';
```

**To:**

```
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
```

and as mentioned in the comments change `chareset` to `charset`

**Edit:**

if your sending a txt/html mail you have according to [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) to set mime in the headers too so try this

```
    $to = $this->post_data['register-email'];
    $message = 'Hello etc';

    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: Website <admin@example.com>' . "\r\n";
    mail($to, 'User Registration', $message, $headers);
```

If it still doesn't work you could try to debugg your code, simply add

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

on top of the page, and take it from there, and if you still can't solve it by yourself post it here and I'll do my best to help ya out.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question with the new code that still doesnt work.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using this code on most of my projects:

```
$subject = 'subject';
$message = 'message';
$to = 'user@gmail.com';
$type = 'plain'; // or HTML
$charset = 'utf-8';

$mail     = 'no-reply@'.str_replace('www.', '', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
$uniqid   = md5(uniqid(time()));
$headers  = 'From: '.$mail."\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-to: '.$mail."\n";
$headers .= 'Return-Path: '.$mail."\n";
$headers .= 'Message-ID: <'.$uniqid.'@'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].">\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0'."\n";
$headers .= 'Date: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time())."\n";
$headers .= 'X-Priority: 3'."\n";
$headers .= 'X-MSMail-Priority: Normal'."\n";
$headers .= 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed;boundary="----------'.$uniqid.'"'."\n";
$headers .= '------------'.$uniqid."\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/'.$type.';charset='.$charset.''."\n";
$headers .= 'Content-transfer-encoding: 7bit';

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: I got this error: "Multiple or malformed newlines found". Which was corrected after removing one of \n (there are two) from Content-Type headers line.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to use PHP_EOL instead of \r\n or \n as the line break would then be determined by your environment...

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . PHP_EOL;
```

etc.. hoping this might finally solve your problem!

Comment: Headers should be separated by \r\n no matter what environment, see docs here: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php.

Comment: It ultimately depends on your environement as on Linux PHP_EOL = \n and on Windows as \r\n (the proper CRLF per RFC)

"2.3.7 Lines
...
   In addition, the appearance of "bare" "CR" or "LF" characters in text
   (i.e., either without the other) has a long history of causing
   problems in mail implementations and applications that use the mail
   system as a tool.
"
What's to say that the mail client does not convert properly those instances..
AFAIK I've never had trouble on linux with email and never had double lines because of \r\n as is neither!

Comment: But PHP_EOL has nothing to do with the spec for an email. In my experience, assuming that something *might possibly* convert something is a recipe for a bugs, if not now, in the future.

Comment: You're right in that a bug is easily introduced by lack a of understanding but in this case, i tend to think that following the RFC to the bit is a little exagerated! In the end the most valuable response to the initial post is to actually use a library such as SwitfMailer::MailTransport (btw it uses a condition if not on linux and not using SMTP to actually replace \r\n with PHP_EOL in headers, body and in [this github recent commit](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/commit/cff72ef856d9aa3f6d7d221eea94ed939539d74b) the subject too :) it's been like that for a while now!